# How to remove AddThis fragment identifiers (hash) from Facebook button? (Twitter's worked)

Tags: javascript, facebook, addthis

I'm trying to use Twitter and Facebook AddThis buttons in my Web app, and don't like to use those redundant fragment identifiers. However, for some reasons when I disable its tracking functionality in my app, it works only on Twitter button and not on Facebook button. I don't see any differences between the two buttons code...

Anyway, here's my code snippet:

```
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
       <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2 btn-addthis" addthis:url="path/to/my/url"></a>
       <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1 btn-addthis" addthis:url="path/to/my/url/same/with/the/above"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var addthis_config = addthis_config||{};
                    addthis_config.data_track_addressbar = false;
                    addthis_config.data_track_clickback = false;
    </script>
```

I implemented the second `<script>` in order to disable the fragment identifiers. However, when I tapped the Twitter button, the hash was successfully removed completely and just the url was there. However, the Facebook button didn't work, and the hash remained to be there for some reasons.

Why does this occur? I tried to move the second `<script>` tag before the first `<script>` but it didn't change at all (by the way which `<script>` should I write the first?)

And also, the reason I swapped the button with `.addthis_button_preferred_1` with the one with `.addthis_button_preferred_2` is that I want to display the twitter button before the Facebook button, but for some reasons, it's not swapped properly at times (about 15 ~ 20 % of the time) and the Facebook button is displayed first for some reasons... Maybe the whole AddThis functionality doesn't work...?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use preferred if you want facebook and twitter only. Because if you use preferred it will set the share buttons to that users preferred social community. addthis_button_facebook for facebook and addthis_button_twitter for twitter.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
   <a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:url="path/to/my/url"></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_twitter" addthis:url="path/to/my/url/same/with/the/above"></a>
</div>
```

I don't think you need the script, but if you do try instead to remove the class addthis_toolbox.